# Changing kml marker in esri javascript api

Tags: arcgis-maps-sdk-javascript, markers

I can load my kml file but I want to be able to define a marker for my points.  I can't find anywhere in the api which allows me to define the marker.

How can you define your own marker using a kml file with the esri javascript api?